# Mice Function in R stuck on first iteration / imputation

Tags: r, r-mice

I've been trying to use mice on my dataset, but it's getting stuck on the first iteration / imputation and it's not running anymore after that. The dataset is 282 rows and 190 columns, so not particularly large / slow to impute. I've tried multiple times, and each time I try it gives me an error regarding the Rcpp package (see below), and then the 2nd time (whether or not I install Rcpp package) it'll run but get stuck on the first imputation. My R Studio then gets frozen and I have to force quit the application. Please help! And please let me know if you need anymore information.

here's the code from my console:

```
> tempA1miced = mice(Analysis1people, seed = 5, m=1)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  VCAM.V.sdt1Error in matchindex(yhatobs, yhatmis, donors) : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
> library(Rcpp)
> #mice analysis 1
> tempA1miced = mice(Analysis1people, seed = 5, m=1)

 iter imp variable
  1   1  VCAM.V.sdt1
```

Image of code in console

[image]

Comment: Do you have missing data in all 190 columns? What is the percentage of missing data (max and min over 190 columns)? Try running the first 50 columns to see if that gives you a result.

Comment: Hi dcarlson, thank you for the response. I was able to solve my issue. The problem was that my packages needed to be updated. Once I installed the updates for my packages, then it ran without freezing!

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem. But since I was realized that the missing data should be in factor (as.factor), or you should check that those are already included as factor. Then, it works with MICE.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).